# Pass value from a Spring meta-annotation to another annotation

Tags: spring-annotations

My use case:
I will have a lot of `@PreAuthorize` annotation in the form `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('RESPECT_MY_AUTHORITY')")`.
I'd like to create a meta-annotation `@HasAuthority` which takes the authority as a value and pass it to `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(<value>)")`.

It feels like it's not possible. The closest I get to what I want is something like the `@AliasFor` annotation. but the problem is that I can't add anything to the value I'll get in `@HasAuthority`. So I would have to repeat the hasAuthority part everytime.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('RESPECT_MY_AUTHORITY')")
public @interface HasAuthority {

    @AliasFor(annotation = PreAuthorize.class, attribute = "value")
    String value();

}
```

I'd like something like:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(#value)")
public @interface HasAuthority {

    String value();

}
```

Any idea how I could do that, or if it's possible at all?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @UKoehler nope, not really. For now I just put the whole `hasAuthority('RESPECT_MY_AUTHORITY')` in a _constants_ file so that I can statically import those strings and use `@PreAuthorize(RESPECT_MY_AUTHORITY)`.